# Is there a /kill command in Minecraft 1.13 if you touch a certain block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

My friend and I play a lot on our own server with cool commands to enhance how we play. Her character is an endermen and we were wondering if there was some sort of command we could use so that when she touches water it will kill or hurt her in some way.  Ive already tried something like `/execute as @e[Team=red] at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:blue_wool run kill @s` but it didnt work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can't capitalize the `team` tag.

This works for me: `/execute as @e[team=red] at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ blue_wool run kill @s`